# Thoroughly understanding the LBB condition

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-operators, finite-element-method

I'm a mechanical engineer who's just gotten into FE analysis. The more I read about FE methods for Navier-Stokes, the more I run into the "LBB condition". I understand that it talks about the order of the interpolation fields for the pressure and velocity fields and how the velocity field must be of a higher order than the pressure field. I see that its an "inf-sup" condition and all that jazz. What I don't understand is all the notation and background that is assumed when people talk about this stuff i.e. all the prerequisites.

I was hoping some one here can recommend a textbook that caters to someone who is on the sophomore-junior level that can thoroughly understand what the LBB condition is. Thanks!

Comment: I would mention Brezzi-Fortin book "mixed finite element methods: theory and applications". In addition to the theory behind lbb, they also have a section on practical aspects (at linear algebra level)

Comment: Being a mechanical engineer, you could also take a look at [chapter 4.5 of Bathe's FE book](http://web.mit.edu/kjb/www/Books/FEP_2nd_Edition_4th_Printing.pdf)